# Why is my CSS anchor style being overridden?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to re-theme [ScrewTurn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/). There's a basic structure to the page which is documented here:

> [ScrewTurn Wiki Theming Reference](http://www.screwturn.eu/Dev.ThemingReference.ashx)

There's some predefined classes for different types of links, for example:

```
a, a:link, a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #D9671E;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a.externallink {
    background-image: url(Images/ExternalLink.gif);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 14px;
}
a.internallink {
}

/* Link to a .aspx page */
a.systemlink {
}

/* Link to a Wiki page */
a.pagelink {
}
```

I need to change the color of these links depending on which container they reside in. The reason being is that my header is dark blue and my side bar is white.

I tried this:

```
/* Make header links white because of dark background */
#HeaderDiv a.pagelink, a.systemlink, a.externallink {
    color: white;
}

#SidebarDiv a.pagelink, a.systemlink, a.externallink {
    color: darkblue;
}
```

However the `#SideBarDiv` color overrides the the `#HeaderDiv` links. The `SideBarDiv` container is not a child of `HeaderDiv`.

The links in the containers simply set the class depending on what they do, i.e.:

```
<a href=".." class="systemlink">Logon</a>
<a href=".." class="pagelink">Some wiki article</a>
```

What am I missing here? Bear in mind I'm a complete freshman when it comes to CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to qualify all your `a` selectors with their respective `div` ID selectors:

```
#HeaderDiv a.pagelink, #HeaderDiv a.systemlink, #HeaderDiv a.externallink {
    color: white;
}

#SidebarDiv a.pagelink, #SidebarDiv a.systemlink, #SidebarDiv a.externallink {
    color: darkblue;
}
```

Otherwise the last two parts of the second ruleset end up overriding styles for *all* `a.systemlink` and `a.externallink` elements in your pages.

Comment: You're a star!! Bloody hell another sodding timer that won't let me tick this as the correct answer for 11 mins.